# How to change reference in created import function in R?

Tags: r, function, reference

I tried to create a function that allows me to import file quickly, but I could not import it with the name I wanted.

The code is as following:

```
g.import<- function(x) {
  x <<- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep=",")
  assign('x',x,envir=.GlobalEnv)
  return(head(x,3))
}
g.import(x=a)
```

I will get the imported file named x, but I want to be able to change the name...

Comment: When you call `g.import(x=a)`, are you trying to save the result as the variable `a` in the global environment? Do you want that parameter to be a symbol rather than character value?

Comment: In `assign`, try changing `"x"` to `deparse(substitute(x))`.

Comment: I want to save the file I imported as data `a` in global environment. I guess that makes it a character value?

Thanks for edting, @MrFlick.

Comment: @Alex A. After I changed `"x"` to `deparse(substitute(x))`, the error showed up like this:
`Error in assign(deparse(substitute(x)), x, envir = .GlobalEnv) : 
  object 'a' not found`

Comment: Why???  This seriously violates the functional paradigm and you save only a few key strokes.

Comment: @Roland I am not quite following. Can you explain which violation you are referring to? Thanks

Comment: In R functions should usually have a return value and no side effects. The only exceptions are side effects like plotting or creating a file. You can just do `a <- read.csv(file.choose())`. Your approach doesn't save much typing, but violates a core principle of the language, namely that it tries to be a functional language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `<<-` and `assign()` parts are redundant. If you want to call with a character value, you can use

```
g.import<- function(x) {
  z <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep=",")
  assign(x,z,envir=.GlobalEnv)
  return(head(z,3))
}
g.import(x="a")
```

to call with an unquoted symbol, you can use

```
g.import<- function(x) {
  z <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep=",")
  assign(deparse(substitute(x)),z,envir=.GlobalEnv)
  return(head(z,3))
}
g.import(x=a)
```

Comment: Although I yet to understand the difference between character value and unquoted symbol, both function works well in importing data. Thanks, @MrFlick !